# OAuth2 Hybrid flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

[Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) uses a term Hybrid flow as if it is a combination of [Oauth's](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) Implicit Grant and Authorization Code Flow. I can not find Hybrid flow documented in the standard however the standard does say, " The implicit grant is a simplified authorization code flow optimized for clients implemented in a browser..."

Where is Hybrid flow documented? Is it another standard?

Answer (score 0):

In a standard `auth code` flow, the tokens are passed through the back channel.

The `hybrid` flow is very similar to the `authorization code` flow, but allows you to receive an access token, and/or ID token in the initial response along with the `code`, through the front channel.

Microsoft briefly touches on it in the authorization code documentation. (see: [Request an ID token as well or hybrid flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-id-token-as-well-or-hybrid-flow))

This is also in the OpenID Connect specifications (see: [Authentication using the Hybrid Flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridFlowAuth))

Comment: Thank you for your response Scott. You described the Hybrid Flow but I was wondering what standard originally defined it. The OpenID Connect Specification  defined it in its [terminology](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Terminology) as being defined in OAuth2 but I have not seen it mentioned in the OAuth2 standard.
Hybrid Flow
"OAuth 2.0 flow in which an Authorization Code is returned from the Authorization Endpoint, some tokens are returned from the Authorization Endpoint, and others are returned from the Token Endpoint."